# Spring security - grails restrict with in role

Tags: grails, spring-security

In spring security, if so many users comes under one role, is it possible to filter users having the same role?

Comment: hm. Restrict urls to selected users, though they have the same role, i.e access restriction more than role level. is it possible / correct to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using [ACL support for the Spring Security plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl). See docs and try it out.